# The intuition behind attention mechanism in Optical Character Recognition

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, ocr, attention-model

I am working on Automatic Number Plate Recognition. So far, I have collected 2428 images, manually labelled them with license number. I went through architectures such as CRNN, attention-OCR and STN-OCR. Tried CRNN. The result were satisfying on a synthetic dataset. But too vague on real images. So, I am planning to use attention-OCR. Before implementing attention, I manually checked how the features look like when given to mobilenet. It was observed that the 5'th channel of the output from layer block_5_depthwise_BN, is focusing more on text region in the plate image. But other channels are not behaving the same. My doubt is, if i pass this layer to an attention block, will it be able focus more on this channel? I would like to get valuable suggestions for the architecture?